# SQL Select and if empty, run another select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in which I have to select an id but if it is not present, I'm going to look for another (with the same value). The two ids are:

- CartId
- SessionId

I have tried:

```
    SELECT TOP(1) CartId 
        FROM Cart 
        WHERE (UserId = @UserId)

if @@rowcount = 0
    SELECT TOP(1) CartId 
        FROM Cart 
        WHERE (SessionId = @SessionId)
```

If the first condition is not satisfied, I get multiple answer (first empty and the second identification). The answer must be unique.

Comment: Please tag with SQL dialect. I assume Microsoft [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine this into one query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) CartId 
FROM Cart 
WHERE UserId = @UserId OR SessionId = @SessionId
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN UserId = @UserId THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Comment: Thanks! This order by is really needed? It does not matter the order on WHERE condition?

Comment: without the ORDER BY, the query would be no longer deterministic, you could get either of the two records - unless their existence is mutually exclusive - so you very likely do need ORDER BY

Comment: @JakeManet . . . Yes.  You want the `UserId` match to be prioritized over the `SessionId` match.